# How many density-independent pixels is one unit of measurement in Blender 2.7x?

Tags: units, measurement

I would like to know how many density-independent pixels it takes to make on blender unit. Please?

Comment: do you mean how many (rendered) pixels are there in a blender unit?

Comment: What are "*density-independent pixels*", could you clarify? There is absolutely no correlation, direct or indirect, between pixels and Blender units, unless you are using some sort of orthographic camera for rendering.